# Conditionally change opacity of all nodes and edges recursively (d3)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, recursion, d3.js, filtering

**UPDATE: [I have created a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkevb7b/7/). Please post an updated fiddle with your answer.**

I have dynamic filters that the user can apply to data but they change the opacity of the nodes to indicate what is filtered in and out (the filtered "out" elements are still partially visible and the actual d3 `filter()` function is not used (intentionally)). I also set a property on each node that is filtered out (e.g. `node = {"name": "test", "isFilteredOut": true};`). ***So for the purposes of this question, even though I am using the word "filter", it is really just a conditional style change*** (and I will try to put the word "filter" in quotes in this post as a reminder of this).

This all works fine, but now I want to recursively "filter" out all children nodes and edges of "filtered-out" nodes, and also the edge connecting the initial "filtered-out" node to its non-filtered-out parent node.

***All of the examples I can find begin with a click event and thus have the luxury of using `this` to get the data for the initial node selected. I do not have this luxury*** because the filter is applied using a UI element that is not within the graph itself.

I currently "filter" the nodes like so:

```
node.style("opacity", function(n) {
    if (my_filter_conditions) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        n.isFilteredOut = true;
        return 0.1;
    }
});
```

What I essentially need to do is:

1. Recursively select all children nodes of currently "filtered-out" nodes and "filter" those out also (i.e. change their opacity to 0.1 and set `n.isFilteredOut = true;`).
2. Change the opacity of all edges to 0.1 where the source node *or* target node are "filtered out" (i.e. `n.isFilteredOut = true;` on either end of the edge)

## What I tried

I don't know how to access the data of the source and target nodes given only the index of each from the edges (remember I have no `this` node to start with from a click event). I tried passing the node index obtained from the edge to obtain the node data with:

```
var node_data = d3.select(current_edge.source.index).datum();
```

However, this resulted in errors from the d3 library related to `this.node()` being null (so passing the index here did not work).

I also tried handling edges by nesting the function for handling links inside the function passed to the `node.style()` function but then it tries to deal with *all* edges on *every* node and I can't get it to provide the desired result.

```
link.style("opacity", function (e) {
    return ( (n.isFilteredOut)
            && (n.index==e.source.index | n.index==e.target.index) ) ? 0.1 : 1;
});
```

This was my attempt to "filter out" edges on both sides of "filtered-out" nodes, but none of the edges were ever filtered out when I used this for some reason (it appeared as if nothing happened at all).

**UPDATE: [I have created a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkevb7b/7/).**

**Notes on the fiddle:**

- I'm aware that it is simplistic (it's supposed to be a minimum working example)
- The actual application contains filters that apply within types (even if just a search for a specific device/part/etc.), so it is important that the logic be able to conditionally follow the "chain" only for those nodes with `node.isFilteredOut = true;`
- In this example, the correct answer will result in creating a situation where **filtering out devices will also filter out all parts**
- Solutions that do any filtering using `dataSet` itself will not work, because much of my data is dynamically populated from various JSON sources. Feel free to work with `nodes`, `edges`, `links`, `node`, and/or `link`.
- Please do not rewrite my filtering methodology. Yes, I know `eval()` statements aren't great. But this is not a question about how to best apply infinite conjunctive filters, but about recursively changing the opacity of nodes and edges based on the filters applied

Comment: without a fiddle, it quite difficult. Can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: I've added a fiddle: **UPDATE: [I have created a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkevb7b/7/).**

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer FYI: [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkevb7b/7/)

Comment: And to clarify, in my simplistic fiddle, filtering out devices should also result in all parts (and links/edges) being filtered out as well.

Comment: Tricky situation. Neither answer actually has been demonstrated to work (the one that posted the fiddle actually breaks existing functionality and doesn't do what is needed and the newly posted one was admitted by the author that it won't work with D3). Yet to award no one means the points are wasted. Arg...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach, that implements both the recursive filtering (if a device is filtered, its parts are filtered), and the filtering of links based on the filtering of their nodes: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsr9c8nL/4/

I have changed the way you implement the filter. Using strings to build the filter, and then `eval()` is considered pretty bad these days, because tools cannot do much with `eval()`, for instance to detect errors or optimize the JS code on the browser.

I do the filtering directly on the `dataSet`, not on the nodes (where you had to query the node's `type` and compare strings, which is slow). Doing so directly on the dataSet also allows easily finding what is the device, for a given part.

The trick is basically to redraw the whole diagram every time, and carefully use d3's `exit`, `enter` and `update` selections. This will also allow you to add animations if you want

Comment: The updated version does not filter out the nodes nor their labels anymore, only the links. Also, my actual code has numerous filters and the conjunctive AND logic is very important (it's not always a simple "turn off all of this type", there are filters within types). They are not all simple on/off filters either. This "undid" some of the existing functionality. Also, my fear with this method is time. It takes about 5-10 minutes to "draw" my data set initially. Filters are instantaneous using my existing methodology. This will take 5-10 min to apply filters.

Comment: Is there any way you can keep my existing filtering methodology and operate directly on nodes and links/edges to get the same kind of result? This will become too complicated with lots of filters that cross types and are within types and redrawing will be a huge performance hit since I'm actually pulling from multiple JSON sources and dynamically populating many fields.

Comment: Seems like you should first start by optimizing that initial display. No user is going to wait 10min for a compute to display a graph. My guess is that all the string manipulation and DOM access you are doing are slowing things down. Seems also like you should split your data into smaller bunches so that the layout is computed more efficiently.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to use your existing approach, but using `eval` is so not recommended these days that I definitely recommend you consider other approaches. It is slow, error prone, no tool can check your code or optimize it.

Comment: It's a small user base and it is loading a massive amount of dynamically generated information (some of the speed issues are not the fault of the graph).

Comment: Understood, but when I have to chain together potentially hundreds of filters, searches, date ranges, etc. conjunctively (using AND logic), I don't know a better way to do it without writing a crap-ton of if-else logic that ends up not working right because it becomes order-sensitive rather than conjunctive. My filters must all be in a chained-together condition separated by `&&` (AND) (I was trying to follow [this advice](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/331574/47835))

Comment: Even if you've changed my filtering method, if you can gt your fiddle to so what is intended without losing the existing functionality of my original example, I will award this the bounty (but it goes away in 10 hours). Currently I can't because it actually removed existing functionality that is needed (the nodes and labels no longer become opaque).

Comment: Much better, has my upvote, but can't accept until filtering out devices also filters out parts.

Answer (score 0):

I know you feel strongly about your use of eval here, but you could just refactor your filtering functions to return a lambda:

```
function filter_devices() {
    return n=>n.type != "mobile device";
}
```

and then make something like this:

```
function isNTrueForAll(arrayOFuncts,n){
return arrayOFuncts.every(i=>i(n))

}
```

Or with reduce, if you don't have Array.every:

```
function isNTrueForAll(arrayOFuncts,n){
return arrayOFuncts.reduce((current,next)=>{return current && next(n)},true)

}
```

Or make a recursive iterator if that's more your bag.
Point is, conditional boolean evaluation and delayed executions are not something you need eval for, and you take a big perf hit running eval.

-#Edit-

Looks like the DOM doesn't actually reflect the relationship between your device and part nodes here, so you can't use a D3 selection object to relate a particular part node to it's parent device node.

Thus, recursively selecting the children is sort of a moot point.

Alternatively you could just adjust your filter functions to reflect the relationship - IE, if we're filtering by part, return false for device or part.

That's only really a sustainable solution if there aren't that many filtering conditions and you already know the business logic you'd want to use ahead of time to filter them, but, it could work for you.

Comment: A couple questions: 1) can you update the fiddle to show this in action (and prove it works)? 2) will using lambda functions still work if some of my filters require 50+ lines of code to work (they are more complex than those in my fiddle)? My understanding of lambdas in Python is they must be short and on one line.

Comment: 1) Well, I have one that -would- work if the DOM relationship between nodes reflected inheritance, but, it's all flat, so, that was a bad assumption on my part - D3 'selections' aren't going to work for your example.
2) There is not really any upper limit to a lambda in JS. It changes 'this' context to be the 'this' context of the calling parent, elsewise, it's basically just syntactic sugar for a function def. They could be of arbitrary length or complexity.

Comment: lambda in python must be short, but in javascript there is no such limitation. Building your filters via functions that return other functions and combine them is a fairly good idea likely. Will be faster, safer, and easier to optimize by the js engine, then using `eval()`

Comment: If I could see an example in the fiddle, that would be very helpful. The issue for me is that the functions are not all present every time. Only the selected filters are in the if condition. So how do I dynamically include functions in an if condition?

Comment: I was unable to make a fiddle that worked because I couldn't relate, from a D3 selection object, the device node to it's part node, since the DOM doesn't illustrate that relationship.

If you just want something that illustrates using lambdas and dynamic evaluation, but still has the same problem, here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbkevb7b/16/